Generation of safe global addresses
i know there are 16^40 (hex) or 8^20 (byte/octa) possible addresses.
how is the address in safe global generated?
as far as i can reed it is not generated based on the signers.
also the safe address itself has no private key.
so my guess is that it is randomly generated and that it is the smart contract that can control it. (the contract requires e.g. 2 out of 3 signers)

Addresses for Safe are generated using Arachnid CREATE2. That's correct, the Safe contract itself doesn't have any private key and is controlled by the owners (or signers) based on the threshold configuration of the Safe.

Thanks Ok so the addresses are not random but based on some hash / the signer?

I.e. hash of the contract's bytecode and a salt

That's correct! These are generated using the create2 function. It uses every detail that initializes a Safe to derive a salt that makes the address unique. So the address will be completely different if you change one of the parameters used for the setup function, for example:
The number of owners
The address of one of the owners
The threshold
And many more.
In addition to that, you can provide a nonce to the deployment function. With this nonce you can ensure that the same setup of owners, threshold, etc. will lead to a different address of the deployed Safe with every different nonce.

Thanks. In principle that address could be the same as a standard wallet address. In fact it will be because there are more private keys than addresses
